# post processing on google urls

Tags: php, regex

I have grabbed some urls from Google search results using a regular expression. It has provided me the links in the format given below. Now, I just want the scheme and the host. Any regex ideas? I tried url_parse, but it does not seem to work because of the prefix '/url?q='.

```
/url?q=http://www.fertile-focus.com/&sa=U&ei=dTTTU7L2A4egugSY44LgAQ&ved=0CCsQFjAEOGQ&usg=AFQjCNEwG9ntbG0ZtqbqjJNSfVTlqQJYmg

/url?q=http://www.genetests.org/&sa=U&ei=dTTTU7L2A4egugSY44LgAQ&ved=0CDgQFjAGOGQ&usg=AFQjCNFiux9o5YIUGP4P8B_oG_J6iD1Y6g
```

now just need

```
http://www.fertile-focus.com
http://www.genetests.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex to match the above mentioned URL's which are preceded by `/url?q=` ,

```
\/url\?q=\K.*?(?=\/&)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tJ0yG2/1)

OR

```
www\.[^.]*\.(?:org|com)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tJ0yG2/7)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$url = <<< 'EOT'
/url?q=http://www.fertile-focus.com/&sa=U&ei=dTTTU7L2A4egugSY44LgAQ&ved=0CCsQFjAEOGQ&usg=AFQjCNEwG9ntbG0ZtqbqjJNSfVTlqQJYmg

/url?q=http://www.genetests.org/&sa=U&ei=dTTTU7L2A4egugSY44LgAQ&ved=0CDgQFjAGOGQ&usg=AFQjCNFiux9o5YIUGP4P8B_oG_J6iD1Y6g
EOT;
$regex =  '~\/url\?q=\K.*?(?=\/&)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $url, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "http://www.fertile-focus.com"
    [1]=>
    string(24) "http://www.genetests.org"
  }
}
```

Comment: Good response, but it still brings the path and query, and the prefix, also.

Comment: where? it's just match the links only.

Comment: Avinash, I have the links, just want to get http://www.fertile-focus.com out of links.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what are you trying to say. You mean this http://regex101.com/r/tJ0yG2/5 ?

Comment: in simple, just want to get 'www.somedomain.com' or 'www.somedomain.org' from a heap of html docs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to achieve this rather than regular expressions.

```
<?php
    $url = "/url?q=http://www.fertile-focus.com/&sa=U&ei=dTTTU7L2A4egugSY44LgAQ&ved=0CCsQFjAEOGQ&usg=AFQjCNEwG9ntbG0ZtqbqjJNSfVTlqQJYmg";
    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($query,$result);
    echo $result['q'];
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/v60LRh)

Comment: I was just thinking about it, and you read my mind and coded it. Great.

Comment: This is the only thing that works on my problem, when I tried to preg_match inside a foreach loop. Great answer. Thanks.